# Unexpected results from this SQL - not getting as many records as expected

Tags: sql

I have the following SQL:

```
SELECT F3003.IRAN8         AS CUST_NO,
       F3003.IRKIT         AS SHORT_ITEM,
       F3003.IRMCU         AS WC,
       F3003.IRDSC1        AS ROUTE_DESC,
       F0101.ABALPH        AS CUST_NAME,
       F0101.ABAC01        AS DIV,
       F4101.IMLITM        AS ITEM_NO,
       F4101.IMDSC1        AS ITEM_DESC,
       F4101.IMUOM1        AS UOM,
       F41021.LIPQOH / 100 AS ON_HAND
FROM   PROD2DTA.F3003 AS F3003
       INNER JOIN PROD2DTA.F0101 AS F0101
         ON F3003.IRAN8 = F0101.ABAN8
       INNER JOIN PROD2DTA.F4101 AS F4101
         ON F3003.IRKIT = F4101.IMITM
       INNER JOIN PROD2DTA.F41021 AS F41021
         ON F3003.IRKIT = F41021.LIITM
WHERE  F3003.IRAN8 > 0
       AND F3003.IRMCU LIKE '%NXT'
       AND F0101.ABAC01 = 'CON'
       AND F41021.LIPBIN = 'S'
```

It seems to be getting the information I need, with one strange exception that I don't understand. Below are samples of data from some of these tables.

We will focus on an item with the short item number = `99898`.

F3003

```
IRKIT   IRDSC1           IRMCU  IREFFF      IREFFT      IRAN8
99898   GLOBAL           NXT    07/27/2021  12/31/2040  11676
99898   GLOBAL           NXT    07/27/2021  01/04/2022  11676
99898   GLOBAL           NXT    01/05/2022  12/31/2040  11676
```

F0101

```
ABAN8   ABALPH           ABAC01
11676   Company XYZ      CON
```

F4101

```
IMITM   IMLITM           IMDSC1                         IMUOM1
99898   7GWPD310150      WIDE WALE D31 COIR SY          SY
```

F41021

```
LIITM   LIPBIN   LIPQOH
99898   S        375
99898   S        375
99898   S        375
99898   S        417
99898   S        375
99898   S        229
99898   S        208
99898   S        375
```

When I run the query above, I get the following results:

```
CUST NO CUST NAME   SHORT ITEM  ITEM NO     ITEM DESC               UOM ROUTE DESC  WC  ON HAND
11676   Company XYZ 99898       7GWPD310150 WIDE WALE D31 COIR SY   SY  GLOBAL      NXT 208.00
11676   Company XYZ 99898       7GWPD310150 WIDE WALE D31 COIR SY   SY  GLOBAL      NXT 229.00
11676   Company XYZ 99898       7GWPD310150 WIDE WALE D31 COIR SY   SY  GLOBAL      NXT 375.00
11676   Company XYZ 99898       7GWPD310150 WIDE WALE D31 COIR SY   SY  GLOBAL      NXT 417.00
```

I was expecting to see 8 lines of results because of the 8 lines of data from F41021. I assume there's a subtle bit of SQL logic that I'm missing to get the results I need.

Comment: I would actually expect to see 3*8 or 24 as each entry in F3003 would tie to each entry in F41041 .  with a minimum of 8 entries   based on  INNER JOIN PROD2DTA.F41021 AS F41021
         ON F3003.IRKIT = F41021.LIITM  so either the key/fk values have non-display characters (such as spaces at the end or tabs or something like that ) or we're not seeing the whole query.

Comment: It appears you have 4 unique values in F41021.LIPQOH are you doing some sort of duplication or group by / distinct you're not showing?  To me it's consolidating those values since they are identical.  I see this in BO sometimes as it hides duplicate rows by default....  is this being done in a query engine or though a UI which may eliminate duplicates for you (like Business Objects or maybe SSRS)?  my guess is if you change one of the 375's in F41021 you'll get 5 instead of 4 rows...

Comment: That is the whole query.

Comment: I am using a reporting package called Hubble that provides a UI where you can use canned reports, build reports by linking tables together with simple join logic, or create what they call a "virtual view" (which this is), where you need to specify the SQL to use. The virtual view gives you the most flexibility, but you have to know your SQL.

Comment: So very weird.  Something is doing a distinct or group by hiding the other rows.  add IREFFF      IREFFT to the select and it should increase the rows.    I'm betting Hubble is doing a distinct...

Comment: Funny you say that. If I do a slight modification of this query where I sum the LIPQOH (on hand quantity), it get 2 or 3 times the sum I expect. I understand the cause for that, which I've been trying to find a way around.

Comment: aggregation needs to occur before the joins or it artificially inflates your numbers; or you have to use analytic functions and partition by keys of the table having the value to sum to get it to work.

Comment: I still think there's something (a setting) in "HUBBLE" which is hiding duplicate rows.  you need to "show duplicate rows" wherever that setting is... or your joins are off and you have a cardinality problem you need to address with your data.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243502/discussion-between-joseph-gagnon-and-xqbert).